# How to return a value if recursive calls don't return a value in scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, primes

I have the following code to determine if a number is a prime number:

```
(define (recIsPrime num n)
    (display num)(display (- n 1))(newline)
    (cond ((= (remainder num (- n 1)) 0) #f)
        (else (if (> n 3)
            (recIsPrime num (- n 1)))))
    #t
    )
```

The numbers will be the same at the first call. The problem I am having is that #t is being returned every time instead of the #f that should be returned when a number between 2 and n is found that it is divisible by.

How can I return #f when such a number is found and bypass the #t that I am trying to return if such a number is not found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Balance your parentheses.  The`#t` is outside of `cond`; it is the last expression in `recIsPrime`, so it always returned as its value.

Just put it inside a `cond`'s branch, like so:

```
(define (recIsPrime num n)
    (cond 
      ( (= (remainder num (- n 1)) 
           0)
          #f )
      (else 
          (if (> n 3)
            (recIsPrime num (- n 1))
            #t
            ))))
```

Having an `if` inside your `cond` is redundant; better to fuse them into one `cond` with three alternatives instead:

```
(define (recIsPrime num n)
    (cond 
      ( (= (remainder num (- n 1)) 
           0)
          #f )
      ((> n 3)
          (recIsPrime num (- n 1)))
      (else
          #t )))
```

Or use logical connectives, as

```
(define (recIsPrime num n)
    (and (not (= (remainder num (- n 1)) 
                 0))
          (or (<= n 3)
              (recIsPrime num (- n 1)))))
```

Looks like you intend to call it as `(recIsPrime num num)` and let it try out the numbers in the descending order. Don't. A number is much more likely to have a smaller divisor than a larger one.

Also, *2* is prime.